# Pagerank badge not issued despite exceeding the minimum criteria

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, badges

I know that badges earned don't necessarily show up immediately, most likely because of caching or the job that handles them only runs periodically (for example, the [pagerank top users page](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/tags/pagerank/topusers) shows only 109 upvotes for me). I also know that the rep we see in our profiles may not be accurate due to users being destroyed, etc.

In this case I waited almost a week since going over the 100 upvote threshold to bring this up just to make sure the above scenarios were not at play. I also verified that I had answered the required amount of non-wiki questions. See below (from [my Webmasters profile](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/users/1253/john-conde)):

[image]

What it boils down to is:

1. There is a bug somewhere that is preventing the badge from being issued. If so, now you know about it. :)

   Or
2. The reporting in our profiles can be misleading and off by a larger then usable margin. If so, maybe we should consider how to better deal with that so questions like this don't litter the SE meta sites?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> These badges are awarded for participating in non community-wiki questions with particular tags. If enough votes are earned in a tag with 100+ total questions, the badge will be automatically created and awarded.

https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/badges?tab=tags

There aren't 100 questions yet in the [pagerank] tag on Webmasters, according to https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/tags/pagerank/topusers.

Comment: Aaaaahhh. I overlooked that one minor detail and it makes all the difference in the world. Thanks for pointing that out.